# maven doesn't package the compiled source files

Tags: maven

I have the following in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> The only classes found in the 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar are from
> org.springframework.boot.loader package. None of the class files
> compiled from my source files is there. Below is the output of maven
> install:
>
> INFO] --------------------< com.stocktrader:stock-trader
>
> > -------------------- [INFO] Building stock-trader 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar
> > ]--------------------------------- [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> > build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:add-source (default) @ stock-trader
> > --- [INFO] Source directory: C:\Users\kannanj\IdeaProjects\ibkr\src\main\java added. [INFO]  [INFO]
> > --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ stock-trader --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered
> > resources. [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties
> > files. [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO] Copying 3 resources [INFO]
> > [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @
> > stock-trader --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to
> > date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources
> > (default-testResources) @ stock-trader --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
> > encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to
> > copy filtered properties files. [INFO] skip non existing
> > resourceDirectory
> > C:\Users\kannanj\IdeaProjects\ibkr\src\test\resources [INFO]  [INFO]
> > --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ stock-trader --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to
> > date [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test
> > (default-test) @ stock-trader --- [INFO] Tests are skipped. [INFO]
> > [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2:jar (default-jar) @ stock-trader ---
> > [INFO] Building jar:
> > C:\Users\kannanj\IdeaProjects\ibkr\target\stock-trader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> > [INFO]  [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.0:repackage
> > (repackage) @ stock-trader --- [INFO] Replacing main artifact with
> > repackaged archive [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> > maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ stock-trader
> > --- [INFO] Installing C:\Users\kannanj\IdeaProjects\ibkr\target\stock-trader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> > to
> > C:\Users\kannanj.m2\repository\com\stocktrader\stock-trader\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\stock-trader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> > [INFO] Installing C:\Users\kannanj\IdeaProjects\ibkr\pom.xml to
> > C:\Users\kannanj.m2\repository\com\stocktrader\stock-trader\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\stock-trader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
> > [INFO]
> > ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Please help before I shoot myself.

Comment: Source files do not belong into the resulting jar file (never)... Why have you configured the `<sourceDirectory>...</sourceDirectory>` Also please format your pasted output correctly... Removed the build-helper-maven-plugin also remove the configured for source directory

Comment: "Source files do not belong into the resulting jar file (never)" - What do you mean? How else can another application import classes provided by this artifact?

Comment: First it looks like an spring boot application which can not being used to be consumed by another project... furthermore to create an artifact which can be consumed by other it's needed to be a jar file which contains compiled classes not the source code.

Comment: I have some common classes in the springboot application which I want to use in another, and am lazy to move those common classes to a non-spring boot artifact. is there a way to specify that the compiled classes from the springboot application should go into the installed jar?

Comment: If you want to use some common parts in another project two possible solutions. First make a multi module build separate the common from the other parts. The commons part will be a simple jar (also possible with some spring support) or create a complete separate standalone project and consume that...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you make your note as an Answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use some common parts in another project there are two possible solutions.

- First make a multi module build and separate the common from the other parts. The commons part will be a simple jar (also possible with some spring support)
- Create a complete separate standalone project and consume that.